# Search specific value in specific field with Azure Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have my data in `Azure Search`. In my structure there are a lot of fields and I have to filter or search using two of them.

One is `Type` defined as `Edm.String` and the other one is `memberOf` defined as `Collection(Edm.String)`.

`Type` has values like `private:Text`, `memberOf` has values like `my.com/field/F001`.

I want apply a filter:

```
filter=Type:'private:Text' AND memberOf:'my.com/field/F001'
```

as result I receive all records. I read Microsoft's documentation but I can't find a solution.

In my code I have

```
SearchParameters sp = new SearchParameters()
{
    SearchMode = SearchMode.Any,
    Skip = currentPage - 1,
    IncludeTotalResultCount = true
};

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchQuery))
    sp.Filter = searchQuery;

DocumentSearchResult<VuSearchData> result = 
         await client.Documents.SearchAsync<VuSearchData>(searchText, sp);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for filters is different than for full-text search. Filters use OData syntax. The subset of OData supported by Azure Search is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search).

The filter you want to execute looks like this in OData syntax:

`Type eq 'private:Text' and memberOf/any(m: m eq 'my.com/field/F001')`

Note the use of `any` and a lambda expression since `memberOf` is a collection field.

Comment: Thank you @bruce-johnston I tried this filter but still received wrong record. The funny thing is I have three records as result when I use `search=`: the first one satisfied the condition. The second has in another field the `memberOf` I'm looking for and then the third (and last) has no relations with the filter at all. If I use `filter=`, search returns all record. If I search only one field is working.

Comment: I think I found the problem. If I use this filter on `Search Explorer` in `Azure Portal`, I receive wrong data. If I use the same filter but in my code, I receive what I expect.

Comment: Can you share the filter that didn't work in Search Explorer?

Comment: `filter=showType eq 'private:Test' and memberOf/any(m: m eq 'my.com/offer/98885')` returns all records; for test, `search=showType eq 'private:Test' and memberOf/any(m: m eq 'my.com/offer/98885')` returns all record. Same filter with `SearchServiceClient` in my code, it is working.

Comment: Try $filter= instead of just filter=. Also, the same syntax will not work in the search parameter.